# 引数で他クラスのUIViewの値を変更したい

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, swift4

こんにちは。

他のクラスのUIViewの値を(例えばsomeView.alphaの値など)引数を利用してボタンを押した時に変更したいのですが、変更されません。
下記のコードですが、ボタンを押した時にそれぞれのcaseまでは到達しているようですが(printで確認しました)、目的のviewのプロパティの値が変わりません。
ちなみに初期状態(ViewDidLoad)では変更されるようです。

ボタンを押した時に値を変更するにはどうすれば良いか教えてください。

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var vHome: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var vSearch: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        selectRd(rd: 3) //ViewDidLoadなんかの初期値では変更できるようです

    }
}

extension ViewController {

    func selectRd(rd reader:Int){

        var animateView:UIView!

        let animateVHome   = vHome
        let animateVSearch = vSearch

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, animations: {
            animateVHome.alpha   = 0.0
            animateVSearch.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: nil)

        switch reader {
        case 2:
            animateView = animateVHome
        case 3:
            animateView = animateVSearch
        default:
            break
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.3, animations: {
            animateView.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Another.swift

```
class Another{
    @objc func buttonTapped(sender : HeaderButton) {
        let vC = ViewController
        vC.selectRd(rd: 2) //このボタンを押した時が変更されません。caseまでは行ってます。
    }
}
```

Comment: あなたのコードはコンパイルエラーになります。省略しすぎず、事象を再現するのに十分なコードを示した方が、より早くより正確な回答が得られるでしょう。仮にあなたのAnother.swiftの3行目が`let vC = ViewController()`だとすると、そのメソッドが実行されても画面に反映されるはずがありません。実際に画面表示を担当しているのとは別のインスタンスを新たに作ってしまっているからです。じゃぁ、どうすれば良いのかと言うのは、コードの断片しかないので書くことができません。そもそもAnother.swiftは`UIViewController`なのでしょうか、それとも別の何かでしょうか?`ViewController`との関係は?ご自身の質問は編集できるはずですので、もっと回答に必要な情報を付け足していただいた方が良いでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

最後のUIView.animateのdelayを少し増やしてみたら、いかがでしょうか？
アニメーションの時間がかぶると、新しいアニメーションが無視されることがありますよね。

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.4, animations: {
            animateView.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: nil)
```